# Error accessing Entity Bean from client side on local environment

Tags: java, ejb, entity-bean

I have created an SampleEntityBean, homeInterface, componentInterface and client side class.
All I wanted to do is to access a method defined in SampleEntityBean (doCalculation).
The EntityBean code is.

```
public class SampleEntityBean implements EntityBean{

@Id

@TableGenerator(name=  " ")
@Column()
Integer key;
public Integer getID(){
    return key;
}

public Integer doCalculation(Integer inputs){
    return inputs*2;
}
/**
 * Default constructor. 
 */
public SampleEntityBean() {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

@Override
public void ejbActivate() throws EJBException, RemoteException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void ejbLoad() throws EJBException, RemoteException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void ejbPassivate() throws EJBException, RemoteException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void ejbRemove() throws RemoveException, EJBException, RemoteException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void ejbStore() throws EJBException, RemoteException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void setEntityContext(EntityContext arg0) throws EJBException, RemoteException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void unsetEntityContext() throws EJBException, RemoteException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
```

}

and homeInterface is:

```
package sampleEntitybean;
import java.rmi.RemoteException;
import javax.ejb.CreateException;
import javax.ejb.EJBHome;
import sampleEntitybean.SampleEntityBean;
public interface homeInterface extends EJBHome{
    public SampleEntityBean create()throws CreateException,RemoteException;
}
```

and componentInterface is:

```
package sampleEntitybean;
public interface componentInterface extends javax.ejb.EJBLocalObject {
    public Integer doCalculation(Integer inputs);
}
```

and client side is:

```
package sampleEntitybean;
import java.rmi.RemoteException;
import javax.ejb.CreateException;
import javax.naming.Context;
import javax.naming.InitialContext;
import javax.naming.NamingException;

public class ApplicationClient {

public static void main(String[] args) throws NamingException, RemoteException, CreateException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Context initial = new InitialContext();
    Context environment = (Context)initial.lookup("java:comp/env");
    homeInterface home = (homeInterface)initial.lookup("SampleEntityBean");
    SampleEntityBean bean = home.create();
    int a = bean.doCalculation(10);
    System.out.println(a);

    }

}
```

the error I get is :

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.naming.NoInitialContextException: Need to specify class name in environment or system property, or as an applet parameter, or in an application resource file:  java.naming.factory.initial
at javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getInitialContext(Unknown Source)
at javax.naming.InitialContext.getDefaultInitCtx(Unknown Source)
at javax.naming.InitialContext.getURLOrDefaultInitCtx(Unknown Source)
at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(Unknown Source)
at sampleEntitybean.ApplicationClient.main(ApplicationClient.java:15)
```

Comment: change your ApplicationClient code line 15 to homeInterface home = (homeInterface)initial.lookup("sampleEntitybean.SampleEntityBean"); and test your program